# WCF Array Always Acting as DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am building a simple self-hosting WCF service that will host a mapping service for multiple products.

Here is my Interface:

```
namespace Eps.Messaging.Mapper.MapperServiceLibrary
{
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMapperService
{
    [OperationContract]
    public MapperOutput Map(String MapperFilename, String Input, GlobalArgument[] InputArguments);

    [OperationContract]
    public List<string> GetAvailableMaps();
}

[DataContract]
public class SymphoniaGlobalArgument
{
    [DataMember]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Value { get; set; }
}
}
```

I simply am inheriting IMapperService and implementing them as needed in the service side.

Here is the config for the binding:

```
<services>
        <service name="Eps.Messaging.Mapper.MapperServiceLibrary.MapperService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Eps.Messaging.Mapper.MapperServiceLibrary.MapperService">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8755/Design_Time_Addresses/Eps.Messaging.Mapper.MapperServiceLibrary/MapperService/" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
```

On the client side I am creating a service reference in Visual Studio and pointing to this location. Upon creating an instance of the service I do this:

```
MapperServiceClient Test = new MapperServiceClient();
Test.Map("Test.map", "Blah", BAD_HERE);
```

Where it says BAD_HERE it is looking for System.Data.DataSet instead of an array.

What am I doing wrong? Or is this correct and I need to do some fancy casting to get it to accept an array?

Answer (score 0):

There's a setting on the [Configure Service Reference dialog box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514724.aspx) that allows you to configure how collection types are dealt with. Modify the value in the `Collection type` combo box to an appropriate type (eg array).

Comment: I have it set to use System.Array for "Collection Types." Is this not the correct setting for it?

I have tried just about every option on there and the same thing is happening.

Comment: @Khirok that seems correct. Could you try generating your proxy using svcutil directly and checking that the types are correct - See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133.aspx for how.

Comment: That produces it with the DataSet type. Coworker just told me he tried this as well and saw that with both an array and a Dictionary.

Comment: @Khirok Sorry, I'm out of ideas. Will not remove my 'answer' for a bit so others don't ask you the same.